# ComboBox keypress and Enter not select the new selected value

Tags: extjs, ext.net

With combobox, when expand and press a char key to select the other value, it show select the value but with enter key press it shrink the list but select the last value.

keypress not support enter key operation in extjs 4.

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="CmbState" runat="server" StoreID="StoreState" Editable="false"
                              HideMode="Offsets" QueryMode="Local" DisplayField="Text" ValueField="Value" TypeAhead="true"
                              ForceSelection="true" TriggerAction="All" EnableKeyEvents="true" EmptyText="Select a State..."
                              TabIndex="3">
                              <SelectedItems>
                                <ext:ListItem Value="Please Select....." />
                              </SelectedItems>
                            <DirectEvents>
                                <Select OnEvent="FillDropdowns">
                                  <EventMask Msg="Updating Carriers. Please wait..." ShowMask="true" />
                                </Select>
                              </DirectEvents>
                              <Listeners>
                                <Select Handler="Combo_selectedIndexChanged(this);" />
                                <KeyDown Handler="return Combofilter(#{CmbState},'Text','Value',e);" />
                              </Listeners>
                            </ext:ComboBox>
```

Comment: This is Ext.Net code, which looks unfamilar to me. Maybe you can post the compiled Ext code.

Comment: I tested my combobox, when I move up or down the selection with arrow keys I can highlight other entries, and when hitting Enter this entry gets selected. I use Ext Js 4.2.1

Comment: try with Editable="false"...

Comment: I guess the KeyDown listener breaks the things.

Comment: will you have any suggestion?